# MySQL Update Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to write a MySQL in my PHP script which will update a field in the database however I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Wrong SQL: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' SET 'currentsong' = '' WHERE 'userid' = '1893''
```

While using this code.

```
$setcurrentsongsql = "UPDATE 'user' SET 'currentsong' = '$currentsong' WHERE 'userid' = '$sql1'";
$setcurrentsong = $db->query($setcurrentsongsql);
```

I'm sure it's something simple however I'm completely baffled. Even if I replace the variables with just a normal string it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: remove the `'` around user, currentsong etc and test again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mySQL uses the backtick <kbd>`</kbd> for column and table names, and apostrophes <kbd>'</kbd> for string constants.  However these aren't needed unless you're using a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) (such as your table is actually *called* "table") or your table or column name contains spaces (such as "my table").

You can use:

```
$setcurrentsongsql = "UPDATE `user` SET `currentsong` = '$currentsong' WHERE `userid` = '$sql1'";
```

Or:

```
$setcurrentsongsql = "UPDATE user SET currentsong = '$currentsong' WHERE userid = '$sql1'";
```

Also, if `$currentsong` comes from an untrusted source, you might want to worry about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 8):

Use back ticks not single quotes for table names and column names.  Try the following:

```
$setcurrentsongsql = "UPDATE `user` SET `currentsong` = '$currentsong' WHERE `userid` = '$sql1'";
```

In MySQL, identifier quote character is the backtick " ` ".  This short page should give you a good understanding of the schema rules, identifiers and so on: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: This answer, by itself is trivial or already answered in the comment. You would get +1 from me, if you had mentioned why op should use back-ticks instated of apostrophes.